# Is `require jquery_ujs` still needed in Rails 5.1?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-rails

I am installing jQuery in my `5.1.x` Rails app via the `jquery-rails` gem.

In the gem setup, they recommend to add these lines to `application.js` by default:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

But, in a Rails `5.1.x` app, you have already this line which doesn't depend on jQuery anymore:

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

I suppose both are doing the exact same thing and one is not needed.

Should I keep both anyway or should I prefer only `jquery_ujs` or only `rails-ujs`?

Comment: Just keep anyone of them.

Answer (score 3):

As of Rails 5.1 jQuery is no longer required for UJS (unobtrusive javascript). So if you have no need of jQuery in your rails app, you can just use

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

On the other hand, if you **do** use jQuery in your app, and use the `jquery-rails` gem, and you should **NOT** require `rails-ujs`, but should instead use:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Requiring `jquery_ujs` along with jQuery can cause issues in the app, and you may see the following JS console error:

`Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded!`

Answer (score 2):

`jquery-ujs` is a thing of the past as of *Rails 5.1*, you don't need it.

Comment: Except if you're still using jQuery. 

`rails-ujs` doesn't support jQuery - it was crafted exactly to get rid of jQuery dependency.

Comment: This is true as long as you aren't migrating an old code base that uses the old patterns. The `rails-ujs` library is not a drop-in replacement if you've been using `jquery-ujs`, especially (mostly?) around ajax requests and the arguments w/ event data changing. It does not seem to be well documented as best I could find and I had some issues where the responses didn't seem to be consistently returned in args as expected. I had to turf the upgrade for now. 

As a note, https://dev.to/nejremeslnici/migrating-from-jquery-ujs-to-rails-ujs-k9m was helpful to get me 95% of the way.