# Rails 6: link_to method: :delete not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an application that uses Rails 6 and Boootstrap gem 4.4.1
In routes i use devise gem:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
```

in `views/layout/application.html.slim`

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title
      = full_title(yield(:title))
    meta[name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' charset='utf-8']
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = render 'layouts/shim'
    = yield(:head) 
  body
    = render 'layouts/header'
    - flash.each do |message_type, message|
      div class=("text-center alert alert-#{message_type}") = message
    = yield
    = render 'layouts/footer'
```

I use link_to to display user logout path with `method: :delete`:

```
= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

but got error `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"` even though in `app/javascript/application.js` i added

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

is there any way around this except using `button_to`?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466430/is-require-jquery-ujs-still-needed-in-rails-5-1

Comment: i use `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Comment: Since you are using jquery-ujs, you should probably use `data: {method: 'delete'}` instead

Comment: @RubyRacer `method: :delete` is a shortcut for `data: {method: 'delete'}` so it makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're following outdated instructions.

- [Rails 6 defaults to Webpacker](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html) and not Sprockets. You're using `javascript_pack_tag` and not the older `javascript_include_tag`.
- Rails 5.1 replaced `jquery_ujs` with `rails_ujs` which removes the jQuery dependency.

The "magical" `//=` comments are called Sprockets directives and do absolutely nothing in Webpacker - its just a comment. Webpacker instead uses the [`import` directive from ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

When you generate a Rails 6 app it actually creates an `app/javascripts/packs/application.js` file which properly sets up Rails UJS, Turbolinks, ActiveStorage and ActionCable.

You can also add it to an existing app by running `bin/rails webpacker:install`.

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

You then need to start the webpacker development server with `./bin/webpack-dev-server` which will serve the assets. Unlike Sprockets its not "bundled" into the `rails server` command.

> is there any way around this except using button_to?

Yes. Fix your javascript setup (recommended) or use `config.sign_out_via = [:delete, :get]` in `config/intializers/devise.rb` to just bury the bug.

However in this case I would really recommend that you use `button_to` as it will let your users log out even if a script error occurs. You can use CSS to style buttons however you want if thats your hangup.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have 1 problem about button_to, in previous version i have made a favorite function that uses link_to and json format to not reload the page. But when using button_to it redirects to the json page

Comment: @HàMai that's not a use case where you would use button_to in the forst place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an error in your JavaScript, check your console, it shouldn’t be a GET but a DELETE (in the network tab it would show a POST with method delete)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Try https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44185.

Basically, method is deprecated, and the new way is to use

```
data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

instead. If this doesn't work, try running the commands

```
rails importmap:install
rails turbo:install stimulus:install
```

first.

It worked for me, at least.